# What is the Jewish belief about atonement for suicide?

Tags: sin, repentance-teshuvah, suicide

Is it possible that the sin of suicide is not forgiveable because the person is no longer living and cannot perform teshuvah? Can the soul repent once it has left this world?

(I did see a question regarding punishment for suicide but my question is regarding any belief in an opportunity for the soul to repent somehow, not punishment.)

Comment: Well, there is a case like someone drinking a slow acting poison that cannot be cured, they should be able to repent before the poison takes effect.

Comment: @DavidKenner. That would be an isolated incident. I was hoping for a more general consensus.